# Using JSON.search to return multiple objects in defiant.js

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Json object with properties of it. I am using defiant.js for searching the JSON with commands similar to XPath.

[image]

Is there a function which retrieves all the objects of json which starts with a prefix? For e.g, all the objects which starts with 'en_' in the above screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath selector... `/*/*[starts-with(name(),"en_")]`

Looks like it works fine with defiant.js@1.3.1 ...

```js
var x = {
    "thing": "cool",
    "en_item": "awesome",
    "en_other": "awesome",
    "inner": {
        "en_thing": "less than cool"
    },
    "en_yetanother": "awesome",
    "notit": "rubbish"
}

alert(JSON.search(x, '/*/*[starts-with(name(),"en_")]'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/defiant.js/1.3.1/defiant.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this before. It did not fetch me what I need.

Comment: @KiranJoshi works for me on defiant.js website (see screenshot). Set up a jsfiddle to try it out perhaps..?

Comment: Can you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mnffpq38/) I want tags starting with 'en_' only at one level and not children of that tag.

Comment: Hey Billy,
That has given me some insight :) Thank you dude :)
However it doesn't cater to my requirement (Probably my requirement was wierd). I have updated the jsfiddle here [https://jsfiddle.net/mnffpq38/3 ] take a look. 

My requirement is to get array of arrays from JSON Search but I understand JSON.Search would give me only arrays which might not be ideal thing for me. However I vote your answer to be right and close this topic :)

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example with `for` cycle added with `hasOwnProperty` check like this:

```
var filteredObject = {};
//obj - your source object

for(i in obj) { 
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && i.indexOf('en_') > -1){
    filteredObject[i] = obj[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am using Defiant.js to avoid loops. This is not the ideal solution which I am looking for :(

Comment: oh, sorry, haven't noticed that